# Divs not scaling properly

Tags: html, css

The red and lime backgrounds are used in order to display it, as the images don't seem to be loading through [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/rdxxn/2tk157z9/15/)

I have been trying to fix this issue for a while by getting all the divs to scale responsively I have managed to get it to scale using absolute values but have had no luck with getting it to scale responsively, any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: It all comes down to what you mean by "scale responsively"... My guess is that you want the background images to fill the whole div. Is that correct?

Comment: Its hard to represent without an image https://imgur.com/a/1ZV3UAt The bar at the left is not going under the areas at the top and upon changing the width of the page the bar would become wider than the connecting areas on the top and bottom and also shorter so it would not reach

Comment: You could make your jsfiddle example work if your url's actually point to images. So, not the page https://imgur.com/a/ehDm3PT but the image https://i.imgur.com/41XAquF.png Having a working example makes it much easier to explain the problem.

Comment: I have updated Jsfiddle to encorporate your advice and it should give you a better example

Comment: You forgot to update the link. It's now: https://jsfiddle.net/rdxxn/2tk157z9/25/ Let me see if I can now understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got a bit further: https://jsfiddle.net/35ayrhg4/

Note that if you want the "top" to go over the left and right it needs to come after the left and right in the DOM (= HTML). This is because things get ordered from back to front in the order of oldest to newest. Here the oldest is the thing that comes first in the HTML.

I didn't use percentages for the sizes but pixels. So `6px` instead of `1.667%`.

The bottom still needs a bit of work, but it is getting there.